# certain default tablet browsers can't pull dataURL?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tablet, data-url

I'm running code that looks for an event trigger based off of drawing on the html5 canvas. Once you stop drawing it sends the dataURL to a input field. From there I save the dataURL to a database.

This works for the following:

Andriod Pads that are running version "icecream sandwhich"
Ipad
PC
MAC

It does not work on the following tablets:
Kindle Fire
Android Pad running "honeycomb"

here is my code to put the dataURL into the input:

```
document.getElementById("dataURLCode").value = canvas.toDataURL();
```

on the ones that works, the output in the field is something along the lines of:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...
```

for the ones that do not work the output code is just this:

```
data:,
```

Things I've tried to clear the cache and history. I'm trying to stray away from using a different browser other than the default one due to we are making this product for cross platform and we need to have it working for all tablets and their default browsers.

I've also pulled a dataURL into the input field no problem by copy/paste, it just cant pull using the canvas.dataURL

I'm assuming the browsers do not support this part of html5 but I'm up for other assumptions.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some version of Android have problems with `toDataUrl();` Here you can find an easy solution:

http://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/wiki/FirstSteps

The script: http://todataurl-png-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/todataurl.js

Paste this in your `head`:

```
<script src="todataurl.js"></script>
```